# A scattermapbox shows but it does not hover

Tags: python, plotly

I have a dataframe df and I do

```
    fig.add_trace(go.Scattermapbox(
                            lat=one_mesh_p['lat'],
                            lon=one_mesh_p['lon'],
                            mode="markers",
                            marker = { 'size': 5, 'color': "blue" },
                            name="hello",
                            hoverinfo = 'text',
                            text=[str(one_mesh_p['id'])],
                            showlegend = True,
            ))

fig.update_layout(margin={"r": 20, "t": 40, "l": 20, "b": 20},
                        title={"text":file_title, "font":{"size":30}},
                        mapbox_style="open-street-map",
                        hovermode='closest',
                        mapbox=dict(
                            bearing=0,
                            center=go.layout.mapbox.Center(
                                lat=center[0],
                                lon=center[1]
                            ),
                            pitch=0,
                            zoom=zoom_level
                        ),
                        )
```

However, although I see the points, there is no hovering
I have checked and `one_mesh_p['id']` has the correct data

Comment: I think we can convert the id to a string and specify the text in the hover template. `hoverinfo = 'text',text=[str(one_mesh_p['id'])],` can be accomplished by changing it to `hovertemplate='%{text}',text=[str(x) for x in one_mesh_p['id']],`.

Comment: I think that did it. Would you like to write an answer to mark it, or would you prefer I write it citing you? (also, it did show what I wanted but also something called "trace 1" that I dont know what it is)

Comment: I encourage you to respond yourself.